# LINQ 2 SQL Using Contains

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert the following SQL statement to a Link2SQL statement.

```
SELECT * FROM Global.CustomData
WHERE CustomDataSource LIKE '%Plugin%'
```

I have converted it to this statement

```
    var query =
      from item in db.CustomDatas
      where item.CustomDataSource.Contains(dataSource)
      select item;
```

And have tried setting dataSource to the following: "Plugin", "%Plugin%", "/Plugin/" and "%/Plugin%/". These I have taken from other examples. Unfortunately, although the TSQL statement does return a value, I cannot get the Linq2Sql statement to return anything. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `"Plugin"`, the only thing I can think of is the case sensitivity. Try something like this:

```
where item.CustomDataSource.ToLower().Contains(dataSource.ToLower())
```

Comment: I tried that but still no luck. I also commented out my where clause, to confirm that I was getting data, and received two lines, one of which had a CustomDataSource of "Plugin-0". I don't think it makes a difference, but I am using .Net 4.0.

Comment: Make sure you point to the right database. Even without `.ToLower()` it should work since the SQL generated for `Contains` is like your SQL. Actually `ToLower` might throw exception when running against database.

Comment: It didn't throw an exception, but I'll remove it anyway. The case does match. Removing the WHERE clause confirmed that I was pointing to the correct database. Thank you for your help.